How to find the smallest element in an array and return the address?
Find smallest

=============
Write a function called find_smallest in find_smallest.s that
finds the smallest element in an array. In the event of a tie (the
smallest element appears multiple times in the list), return the
address of the first occurance of the smallest value.
find_smallest(begin_address, end_address) -> address_of_smallest

It is given the address of the beginning of an array and the address
of the end of the array. Note: end_address is the first address
that is past the valid elements of the array. This is similar to how
in a list with 10 elements, 10 is the first index that is past the
end of the list.
The elements are 64-bit values. You should return the address of the
smallest element in the array.`
This is what I have, but as you can see below it fails most of the tests, what am I doing wrong?
                .global find_smallest
                .text

# find_smallest(begin_address, end_address) -> address_of_smallest
find_smallest:
                bge a0, a1, 4f        # If a0 == a1 (array is empty), exit
                ld t0, 0(a0) #value of the current smallest address value
                addi t1, a0, 0 #storing the address of the current smallest element
                li t4, 1 #index value
                #addi t5, a1, -8
                

1:
                addi t4, t4, 1
                bge t1, a1, 4f
                slli t2, t4, 3
                add t2, a0, t2 #t2 is now element address
                bge t2, a1, 4f
            
                ld t3, 0(t2) #t3 is the value within that address
                blt t3, t0, 3f


2:
                
                j 1b
3:
                mv t0, t3
                mv t1, t2
                j 1b
                
                
4:
                mv a0, t1
                ret
                

submitting rv64-selection-sort step 1 for grading
  solution for step 1 failed
  ReportCard: error parsing unit test results: XML syntax error on line 104: illegal character code U+001B
$ make grade
riscv64-alpine-linux-musl-as -g --warn --fatal-warnings -march=rv64im start.s -o start.o
riscv64-alpine-linux-musl-as -g --warn --fatal-warnings -march=rv64im find_smallest.s -o find_smallest.o
riscv64-alpine-linux-musl-as -g --warn --fatal-warnings -march=rv64im print.s -o print.o
riscv64-alpine-linux-musl-ld --fatal-warnings start.o find_smallest.o print.o
rm -f test_details.xml inputs/*.actual
python3 lib/grader
$ python3 lib/rv64sim -m run < inputs/test.input

!!! output is incorrect:
$ icdiff inputs/test.actual inputs/test.expected
inputs/test.actual                      inputs/test.expected
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 11370 and 11410
                                            ===> 11370
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 11378 and 11410
                                            ===> 11380
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 11380 and 11410
                                            ===> 11380
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 11388 and 11428                   tween 11388 and 11410
    ===> 11388
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11390 and 11428
    ===> 113b0
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11398 and 11428
    ===> 11398                              ===> 11398
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 11390 and 11410
                                            ===> 11398
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 11398 and 11410
                                            ===> 11398
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113a0 and 11428                   tween 113a0 and 11410
    ===> 113b0                              ===> 113d8
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113a8 and 11428                   tween 113a8 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113b0 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113b8 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113c0 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113c8 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113d0 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113d8 and 11410
                                            ===> 113d8
                                        finding address of smallest element be
                                        tween 113e0 and 11410
    ===> 113f0                              ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be
tween 113b0 and 11428
    ===> 113b0
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113b8 and 11428                   tween 113e8 and 11410
    ===> 113f0                              ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113c0 and 11428                   tween 113f0 and 11410
    ===> 113f0                              ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113c8 and 11428                   tween 113f8 and 11410
    ===> 113f0                              ===> 11400
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113d0 and 11428                   tween 11400 and 11410
    ===> 113f0                              ===> 11400
finding address of smallest element be  finding address of smallest element be
tween 113d8 and 11428                   tween 11408 and 11410
    ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be
tween 113e0 and 11428
    ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be
tween 113e8 and 11428
    ===> 11408                              ===> 11408
finding address of smallest element be
tween 113f0 and 11428
    ===> 113f0
finding address of smallest element be
tween 113f8 and 11428
    ===> 11408
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11400 and 11428
    ===> 11418
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11408 and 11428
    ===> 11408
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11410 and 11428
    ===> 11420
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11418 and 11428
    ===> 11418
finding address of smallest element be
tween 11420 and 11428
    ===> 11420


Passed 0/1 tests in 0.72 seconds     
               ``` 


Same as you would in c. Add the size of array element to the pointer each iterration, retrieve value , compare against smallest value so far. if smaller update compared value and store index. Run over the array once, return resulting value.
If done well could be done stackless just in register, with the array in cache. Have fun writing assembler.
